# How to use apply lambda when input function comes from two dataframes

Tags: python, lambda

I have a function that calculates the monthly sales per client. Beacause the terms are different per client, I use a if/elif statement and integer-location based indexing as shown below. The function is called like f('A'). Input data comes from 2 df's; monthly_shipments and discount_bracket with conditions used for lookup. My question: Is it possible to us a .apply(lambda :...) function to run this function on multiple columns?

suppose I have these two df's:

```
df_shipments_monthly = pd.DataFrame({'A': [ 45, 102, 98, 105],
                          'B': [ 301, 150, 205,308]})


     A   B
0   45  301
1   102 150
2   98  205
3   105 308

discount_brackets = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['start_br1', 'end_br1', 'price1','start_br2', 'end_br2', 'price2'],
                          'A': [0,100,10,101,200,9],
                          'B': [0,200,20,201,400,18]
                        }) 
            A    B
Type        
start_br1    0   0
end_br1     100 200
price1      10  20
start_br2   101 201
end_br2     200 400
price2       9  18
```

and this function:

```
def f(x):
    sales = []
    for i in df_shipments_monthly[x]:
        if i <= discount_brackets[x].iloc[1]:
            t = i * discount_brackets[x].iloc[2]
            sales.append(t)
        elif i < discount_brackets[x].iloc[4]:
            if discount_brackets[x].iloc[3] == 0:        # is startvalue bracket 2 zero?
                t= i * discount_brackets[x].iloc[5] 
                sales.append(t)           
            else: 
                t = i *5         # do something else....
                sales.append(t)
    return sales
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acces the column name with x.name in an apply function:

```
def f(column):
    x=column.name
    sales = []
    for i in column:
        if i <= discount_brackets[x].iloc[1]:
            t = i * discount_brackets[x].iloc[2]
            sales.append(t)
        elif i < discount_brackets[x].iloc[4]:
            if discount_brackets[x].iloc[3] == 0:        # is startvalue bracket 2 zero?
                t= i * discount_brackets[x].iloc[5] 
                sales.append(t)           
            else: 
                t = i *5         # do something else....
                sales.append(t)
    return sales 

df_shipments_monthly.apply(f)
```